# Define a coordinate on a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I have the following piece of tikz code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw (2,2) circle [radius=2pt];
\draw (3,3) circle [radius=2pt];
\path[inner sep=0pt] (2,2) ++(45:2pt) node (A) {};
\path[inner sep=0pt] (3,3) ++(225:2pt) node (B) {};
\draw[-] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

where I want to connect two connect the circles with a line. Points A and B should be on the circles, but unfortunately they are slighty off. How can I fix the existing code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A node has usually a contents. In this case, it is empty, but lines between nodes are more complicate, there is `inner sep`, `outer sep` etc., but the center point could be used:

```
\draw (A.center) -- (B.center);
```

There is an easier way. Simpler points can be defined by `coordinate` instead of `node`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
  \draw (2,2) circle [radius=2pt];
  \draw (3,3) circle [radius=2pt];
  \path (2,2) ++(45:2pt) coordinate (A);
  \path (3,3) ++(225:2pt) coordinate (B);
  \draw[-] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or, merged to one `\draw` statement:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\radius{2pt}
  \draw[radius=\radius]
    (2, 2) circle[] ++(45:\radius) coordinate (A)
    (3, 3) circle[] ++(225:\radius) coordinate (B)
    (A) -- (B)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

with defining your circle as node simple solve your problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
krog/.append style={% krog = circle ;-)
    circle, draw, minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}
                        ]
\node (A) [krog] at (2,2) {};
\node (B) [krog] at (3,3) {};
%
\draw (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is also a very good answer, but unfortunately I can only accept one.